# limit of char sprintf() handle

Tags: c++, c, linux

I have got 2 programs.. One to learn and another which consist of disecting it ..so like.. I had a function which calculates game frames per second.

On one of them: `sprintf(FPS, "Immortal Conflicts: FPS: %d,", misc.FPS);`
no problem on the other one

`sprintf(FPS, "Immortal_Conf %d", misc.FPS);`
Could there be a reason why for some reason that when I input more characters in the second function data.. the stack the character or something because the number is like 8 digits long and doesn't change.

It wrote like Immortal_Conflicts: FPS: 8454390345

*ive noticed that when i change it from place.. the it freak out...lol

char FPS[2];

oh it work with FPS[20] =O i didnt know anything about array and characters.. in fact.. i learned something.. lol i found my problem lol

Comment: Have you tried `snprintf`?  http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf

Comment: How's `FPS` defined? Probably a buffer overrun

Comment: snprintf crashed the application..

Comment: im not sure what do u mean by how FPS is defined.. do you mean when do i call the function to calculate it or whats the whole function to calculate it?

Comment: `%d` is for printing integers, not strings.  Use `%s` for printing strings.

Answer (score 3):

There is a buffer overrun as `FPS` can hold only two characters. It needs to be large enough to hold the resulting string.

As this is C++ suggest using `std::ostringstream` to construct your string:

```
#include <sstream>

std::ostringstream FPS;
FPS << "Immortal Conflicts: FPS: " << misc.FPS; // FPS.str() will return a
                                                // std::string of the data.
```